# Generating JHipster app online serves empty page

Tags: jhipster

When I'm generating app from locally installed JHipster 4.7, I can start it on localhost:8080 by running ./mvnw with no problems.

But when I generate the project online at https://start.jhipster.tech, running ./mvnw shows the blank page on localhost:8080 (no errors on the browser's console). To see the page, I have to run `yarn start` and use localhost:9000 (this is optional if I generate the project locally).

Did anyone experience this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Yes in `dev` mode the [JHipster development documentation](http://www.jhipster.tech/development/) is still valid with JHipster Online, which might not be obvious. So indeed you'll need to run `./mvnw` for the backend and `yarn start` for the front-end
- In `prod` mode, running `./mvnw -Pprod` will run automatically `yarn` so you might not see it (as it's automatic), but in the end it's basically the same thing.

In the future that might change, to make things easier: the build could be done in the cloud (or in a local Docker container), so you won't see those at all.

Comment: Thanks. So this is undocumented change. This complicates demos because now for prod mode I'd need to configure my prod DB.

Comment: Oh yes for `prod` mode you need a database, then it's already configured as a Docker Compose file - `docker-compose -f src/main/docker/mysql.yml up -d`

Comment: But for Angular 4 there is no undocumented change: it works the same with the "locally installed" generator or JHipster Online. The only thing with JHipster Online is that you don't need to install the generator. Of course this is just the first step :-)

Comment: With locally-generated app you can just run ./mvnw and see the app on localhost:8080. With online-generated app you must run ./mvnw -Pprod to see the app on localhost:8080. This is inconsistent, but it'll get better, I'm sure :)

Comment: Oh, I understand: that's because when you run it locally, it does a `yarn` build at the end. So in fact it works "out of the box", which is not the case with JHipster Online - totally understood!

Comment: Then, the `yarn` build generates stuff in `target/www`, which is not stored into Git (as `target` is ignored for obvious reasons). So this cannot be automated with a project stored on GitHub (our default option). With our "download as Zip" option, we could have pre-compiled stuff inside `target/www` - which is good but then JHipster Online wouldn't be consistent.