# converted JHipster app to gradle and now returns blank page in dev

Tags: gradle, npm, webpack, jhipster

I have a JHipster app that was generated with maven and I just converted it to gradle.

- I deleted the project, re-generated it with gradle, and went over the changes.

After starting the project (`./gradlew`) when I enter the page at `localhost:8080` I get a blank page back.

When running both `./gradlew` and `npm start` I get the page at `localhost:9000`.

I looked at the blank page and saw that it is my `index.html` file.

I tried the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941832/generating-jhipster-app-online-serves-empty-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585713/jhipster-blank-page) (which seem to describe my problem in other situations) but couldn't find a good fix.

Comment: Please clarify, is it working fine when you run both gradlew and npm start? If you want to run only gradlew without hot reloading client code you must build the front end first (see the scripts section in your pakage.json file). Why did you tag your question with yarn if you use npm? Make sure you don't use both even on different projects, you could get path issues with `jhipster` command if it has been installed globally with both.

Comment: Clarified in question. Gradlew also builds the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I missed changes in the java class `WebConfigurer`:

- in method `setLocationForStaticAssets`.
- in method `resolvePathPrefix`.

In both methods there is a reference to the `target`/`build` directory.

changing these references fixed the issue.